# Is there an XSLT name-of element?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

In XSLT there is the

```
<xsl:value-of select="expression"/>
```

to get the value of an element, but is there something to select the tag-name of the element?

In a situation like this:

```
<person>
  <!-- required stuff -->
  <name>Robert</name>
  <!-- optional stuff, free form for future extension. 
       Using XMLSchema's xsd:any -->
  <profession>programmer</profession>
  <hobby>photography</hobby>
</person>

<xsl:for-each select="person">
   <xsl:tag-of select="."/> : <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

To get output like this:

> ```
> name : Robert
> profession : programmer
> hobby : photography
> ```

Of course the above XSLT won't compile because

```
 <xsl:tag-of select="expression"/>
```

doesn't exist. But how could this be done?

Comment: The most relevant tag for this question is XPath. Both functions are XPath standard functions and can be used within an XPath expression in the context of any hosting language (C#, XSLT, XQuery, ...) Please, re-tag

Comment: This text: "In XSLT there is the

<xsd:value-of select="expression"/>"  -- contains an error. The usually used prefix for XSLT instructions is "xsl". Usually when using XML Schema we use the prefix "xsd" or "xs". Please, correct.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

This will give you the current element name (tag name)

```
<xsl:value-of select ="name(.)"/>
```

**OP-Edit:** This will also do the trick:

```
<xsl:value-of select ="local-name()"/>
```

Comment: local-name is what you want 9 times out of 10

Comment: local-name is sans namespace, this is why it's usually better.

Answer (score 112):

**Nobody did point the subtle difference in the semantics of the functions [`name()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-name) and [`local-name()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-local-name).**

- `name(someNode)` returns the full
  name of the node, and that includes
  the prefix and colon in case the node
  is an element or an attribute.
- `local-name(someNode)` returns only
  the local name of the node, and that
  doesn't include the prefix and colon
  in case the node is an element or an
  attribute.

Therefore, in situations where a name may belong to two different namespaces, one must use the `name()` function in order for these names to be still distinguished.

**And, BTW, it is possible to specify both functions without any argument**:

**`name()`**  is an abbreviation for **`name(.)`**

**`local-name()`** is an abbreviation for **`local-name(.)`**

**Finally**, do remember that not only elements and attributes have names, these two functions can also be used on PIs and on these they are identical).

Answer (score 15):

```
<xsl:for-each select="person">
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/> : <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>  
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: As a good practice always use
normalize-space() when getting value-of the node

<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
This will trim the extra spaces

Comment: Such normalisation/sanitisation would only be needed if it hadn't been handled at the input gathering stage. Doing it then saves having to do it at access time, which is usually far more often. One would do it before adding to an RDB, and an xml document is just another database.

Answer (score 9):

For those interested, there is no:

```
<xsl:tag-of select="."/>
```

However you can re-create the tag/element by going:

```
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,3)"/>
</xsl:element>
```

This is useful in an xslt template that for example handles formatting data values for lots of different elements. When you don't know the name of the element being worked on and you can still output the same element, and modify the value if need be.

Answer (score 6):

```
<xsl:value-of select="name(.)" /> : <xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

Comment: So why'd this get down voted? Granted could've mentioned local-name() if you didn't want the namespace as well, but it would be useful to the wider community to explain why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Perhaps, it couldn't transform the given XML. the name(.) will be "person" in this case. it should be "name", "profession" and "hobby".

Comment: @CodeMelt Why then you didn' downvote the accepted answer? It good, but is even less specific than this one. I up-voted Rowland Shaw's answer as it provides the answer to the question. Plese, downvote only when an aswer contains wrong, incorrect or misleading information

Comment: Fixed that minor detail - personally, i think that people should explain why something is downvoted, as it helps explain the collective knowledge...

Comment: Our reputations may attract attention, but as they are no guarantee that what we have posted is worthwhile, it is the quality of our contribution that really counts. No reasoning makes for poor quality contributions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="person">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:text>
       </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/> : <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```