# How to use for each in jquery?

Tags: jquery, foreach

```
var attr = {node:"<tr> ,id=tr1$<td>,colspan=2,style.width=100%$<div>,id=divlistudcitems$<select>,id=lstListUdcItems,name=lstListUdcItems,size=12,style.width=100%;"}
```

in the above code i will pass the value of attr to a function createHTML where i need to iterate each and every tag (tr,td,div)using jquery for each. Could anyone advice how to acheive this.

```
var root=document.getElementById("target")
createHTML(root,attr);
```

Comment: Identical question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585261/is-there-an-xslt-name-of-element. You should probably search a bit more before posting a new question.

Comment: Thank you..i missed the second loop that makes me confused.    "<xsl:for-each select="*">"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="subclass">
  <xsl:value-of select ="local-name()"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Or

```
<xsl:for-each select="subclass">
  <xsl:value-of select ="name(.)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```