# How to get the value of the currently matched xsl node into a variable?

Tags: sharepoint, xslt

In my xsl, I want to `match` on several nodes and then grab the value of the matched node into a variable.  How can I do that?

I need to place a wildcard variable in place of `Budget0` below:

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='Budget0' or @Name='Scope' or @Name='Risk' or @Name='Schedule']" mode="body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="$thisNode/Budget0" />
    <xsl:variable name="statusRating1">(1)</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="statusRating2">(2)</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="statusRating3">(3)</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($currentValue, $statusRating1)">
            <span class="statusRatingX statusRating1"></span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains($currentValue, $statusRating2)">
            <span class="statusRatingX statusRating2"></span>
        </xsl:when> 
        <xsl:when test="contains($currentValue, $statusRating3)">
            <span class="statusRatingX statusRating3"></span>
        </xsl:when> 
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <span class="statusRatingN"><xsl:value-of select="$currentValue" /></span>
        </xsl:otherwise>                    
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

In this snippet, the `xsl:template match...` works just fine; it does seem to match those fields.  I can see in Firebug that those fields receive the `statusRating1` css class just like they should (since they are all set to receive the value of the `Budget0` field.

**[update]**

I found that if I use this for the variable:

`<xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="current()/@Name" />`

or

`<xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="FieldRef[@Name=current()/@Name"] />`

It will get caught in the `otherwise` tag, and will print the name of the field.  In other words, the html prints

`<span class="statusRatingN">Budget0</span>`

If I try any of Dimitre's solutions (below), it never matches in any of the `when` clauses, and the html is outputted like this (notice the span's text is blank):

`<span class="statusRatingN"></span>`

Therefore, I deduce that the `$currentValue` is only getting the name of the attribute, it isn't referring to value of the node.  I need to refer to the value of that particular node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, after hours and hours and hours and days and months, here is an example (which I fiddled myself [with help from this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42619/custom-field-xsl-name-vs-fieldtype)):

These two lines are the keys (Dimitre's answer was close):

```
<xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
<xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" />
```

Here is the entire function, which reads two different columns and applies the values to either one:

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='YesNo1']|FieldRef[@Name='YesNo2']" mode="body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>

    <xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" />
    <xsl:variable name="yesvalue">Yes</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="novalue">No</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($currentValue, $yesvalue)">
            <span class="yesno yes"><xsl:value-of select="$currentValue" /></span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains($currentValue, $novalue)">
            <span class="yesno no"><xsl:value-of select="$currentValue" /></span>
        </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
            <span class="yesnoN"><xsl:value-of select="$currentValue" /></span>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Seems you've found an answer that works for you... I had a related but slightly different problem, and found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/585290/313756) to perfectly match it.  Leaving that here in case others, like me, find this question before they find the other.  (short version: `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">` was what I wanted.)

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="$thisNode/*[name()=current()/@Name]"/>
```

**Or, alternatively**:

```
<xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="$thisNode/*[name()=$thisNode/@Name]"/>
```

**Or, alternatively (best)**:

```
<xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="*[name()=current()/@Name]"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure?  that seems to only load the value of the first matched element name.

Comment: Maybe the `match` method would have to be adjusted to use this?

Comment: @BGM, Yes I am sure. Why just don't you try this? It isn't the "first matched element name" -- it is all elements, whose name is the string value of the `Name` attribute` of the current node.

Comment: I did try it - it seems to have the same effect as if I had only made a `match` on the first `fieldref` name.  I've restarted the website portal about 5 times all to no effect.  This xsl stuff is complicated to me.

Comment: @BGM, I corrected the answer -- there was an error in using the context.

Comment: Thanks, Dimitre.  I tried that too, but it doesn't do it.  Even with your edit, it still seems to read the value of the first match.  Maybe the problem has to do with the 'match` method?

Comment: Okay, I've tried all three now (you got my vote).  I think I actually understand what we are doing.  However, none of these are getting the cigar...

Comment: @BGM, There is no such thing as "the first match". There is only one, single attribute `Name` and it has a single value. We select the child of the current node, whose name is the string value of the `Name` attribute of the current node. If the `Name` attribute has value "Budget0" then the child named `Budget0` is selected. If the `Name` attribute has value `"Scope"`, then the child named `Scope` is selected, ..., etc., ... Or do you want something else to be done?

Comment: No, what I am saying is that it never matches. It always applies the `otherwise` - no matter which of the three solutions you propose.  `$currentValue` seems to always be blank.  If I use the fieldref name instead of the "wildcard" then it will match that one just fine, but these snippets don't allow for a match.

Comment: @BGM, I haven't seen your XML. How could I know what you want to select??? Do you want to select elements by name, or do you want to select `FieldRef` elements by the value of their `Name` attribute? Please, *edit* the question and add the missing important data.

Comment: We were on the right track, I think (it is Sharepoint, and I can't seem to get the xml, I tried what you proposed to me in another post but to no avail, and you never responded to me in the chat to try and get any further).  There isn't any missing data in the question.  I am trying to match the @name of the fieldref we have matched.  These solutions you suggest do not grab that value.  I can see the outputted html, and `$currentValue` is always blank.  The `match` works perfectly, however.  Can we not get the `value` of the currently matched field?

Comment: @BGM, What do you mean by "the matched field"?

Comment: @BGM, It is meaningless to speak abot XML transformation, when you don't know the XML document on which the transformation must be applied.

Comment: Dimitre, by "matched field" I mean where it says, `<xsl:template match...`  It matches the fields specified, such as `Scope`, `Risk`, etc.  That part works.  But the $currentValue variable is always blank.  I changed the `otherwise` part in my code to output the `$currentVale` and I see in firebug that it is blank.  I'm sorry, I can't seem to get ahold of the xml - it is dynamically generated and I can't see it myself!

Comment: @BGM, You can get the XML document -- just use: `<xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::node()[not(self::*)]"/>` .I wonder how anyone can "write a transformation" if they don't have the source XML document this transformation must be applied upon.

Comment: Could you take another look?  I added some of the xml outputted by your query.

Comment: @BGM, Sorry, but this isn't sufficient information. It *seems* to me that when the template matches a particular `FieldRef` you wantto find some other elements in the document, whose `name()` or `Name` attribute have the same value as the `Name` attribute of the currently-matched element. However, I cant see such other elements in the provided XML document. Also, if you cannot explain which other elements you want to select, are you sure that you know what you want?

Comment: Oh, this is soooo hard!  There is a big list with columns whose names are `Budget0`, `Scope`, `Risk` and `Schedule`.  I only want to add a css class to them using a single function.  I'll just go back to using the same stupid function four different times.  Thanks for your help Dimitre.

Comment: @BGM, If you know the XML document, then this certainly can be done with XSLT.

Comment: Wow, I've tried all three of these lines and they each seem to crash the entire web part.  Dimitre, are you still around?

Comment: Hi Dimitre.  It's just the standard Sharepoint fldtypes.xsl page - anybody who knows anything about Sharepoint knows all about it.

Comment: @BGM, It isn't reasonable to expect XSLT experts to know anything about SharePoint.

Comment: Maybe to a degree (which is why I tagged my question `sharepoint` - but they are usually pretty good about being able to abstract a little, and have gotten other answers here.  Anyway, it's solved now, and it's there for the record in case anyone else needs it.