# Getting the name of Node in xslt

Tags: xslt

I have a xml drafted as follows

```
<node1>
  <node2>
    <node3>
      val3
    </node3>
    <node4>
      val4
    </node4>
  </node2>
</node1>
```

i m using XSLT to get values from node3 and node 4
So far so good and I m getting the values. 
as

```
val3
val4
```

I m using the xslt loop as follows

```
<xsl:for-each select="/node1/node2">

</xsl:for-each>
```

Now I need to get the names of nodes also.
i.e. i need the following output

```
node3: val3
node4: val4
```

Comment: Yes. you can.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585261/is-there-an-xslt-name-of-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for instance :

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="node1/node2/*">
      <xsl:value-of select="name()"/> : <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:for-each>  
  </xsl:template>
```

I get :

```
node3 : 
      val3
    node4 : 
      val4
```

Comment: I tried this but I m getting something like Node2: val3
node2: val4...I did not use  <xsl:template match="/"> tag though..