# How to get the element name in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm editing an XSL file, and having trouble getting the name of an element.

Everything here works except for `../../name()`.  What I'm *trying* to do there is get the name of the element.  Everything beneath it successfully gets the attributes of that same element, so hopefully the fact that `../../@name` (etc.) works should make clear what I'm trying to do with `../../name()`.

```
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="../../name()" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="../../@name"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="../../@alias"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="../../@comment"/><xsl:text>...</xsl:text></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="../../dxl:wassignedby" /></td> 
<td><xsl:apply-templates select="."/></td>
</tr>
```

The piece of XML (in case it helps you visualize what I'm talking about) is:

```
<form name="Extended Content" alias="CONTENT" hide="notes" nocompose="true" noquery="true" publicaccess="false" designerversion="8">
```

I'm successfully getting (e.g.) "Extended Content" with `../../@name`, but not getting "form" with `../../name()`.

Comment: You're _"not getting 'form'..."_ - what _are_ you getting?  Please show the actual output for the template.

Comment: With what I have there I get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../name()" />
```

Works only in XPath 2.0 where:

```
<xsl:value-of select="name(../..)" />
```

works in both XPath 1.0 and 2.0. So I guess you are running XPath 1.0 and you should use the latter one.

Comment: An XPath address cannot end in "/", so where you have `name(../../)` you need `name(../..)`.

Comment: @G.KenHolman Thx for the advice, should have spent second to think about after copy and paste ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass in a parameter to name(). The param to pass to name would be

```
name(.)
```

the period means current node. Here is a link that explains it better. [Is there an XSLT name-of element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585261/is-there-an-xslt-name-of-element)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was aware of the existence of `name()` but I couldn't get it to work.  So it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @iconoclast ok I removed it.

Comment: @JackThor I felt the inclusion of the link to the other question was really good because it also mentioned `local-name` which in reading the answers to that question is usually the best way to get an element name. So I would either include information about that or add the link back in.