# How to get tag name in XSLT?

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I made a simple example of `xslt`. I want to show tag name in `h2`. How to show the tag name using xslt?

Here is my code: [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/TN1BN5Yao5Z63RDcBGlN?p=preview)

I used this

```
<!--h1><xsl:value-of select="abc/p/name(.)"/></h1-->
```

It gives me an error. Why?

Expected output:

**"P"** (first tag inside abc tag)

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself, not in external links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt:

```
<xsl:value-of select="abc/p/name(.)"/>
```

will work, provided your processor supports XSLT 2.0.

In XSLT 1.0, you need to do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="name(abc/p)"/>
```

which will also work in XSLT 2.0, of course.

Comment: could you please tell me why call function is not working https://plnkr.co/edit/TN1BN5Yao5Z63RDcBGlN?p=preview

Comment: I suggest you post a separate question. Hint: `xsl:call-template` must be in a template that matches something in your input..

Comment: ok ..here is my Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033174/why-function-is-not-called-in-xslt

Answer (score 0):

First of all: add a `<xsl:template match="text()" />` to avoid unwanted output.

Then I would change the first template to match you `abc` because this is the interesting parent node. If you want any child of the node, use `abc/*`. Then the template will match `abs/p` and `abc/catalog`. But you only want the first child, right? So use `abc/*[1]`. This will only match `abc/p`. And now you can do the `name(.)` or `local-name()`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="abc/*[1]">
    <html>
      <body>
       <h1><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></h1>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Your XML-File

```
<abc>
    <p test='ravi'>test123</p>
    <catalog>
        <cd>
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>Columbia</company>
            <price>10.90</price>
            <year>1985</year>
        </cd>
    </catalog>
</abc>
```

Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/585290/5413817

Comment: what is the usee of this `<xsl:template match="text()" />
`

Comment: why I am getting unwanted error ? without this line `<xsl:template match="text()" />`

Comment: the tamplate match everything unmatched before. It is a kind of `default` in a switch-case.