# why function is not called in xslt?

Tags: jquery, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to call function .But it not display out .here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/TN1BN5Yao5Z63RDcBGlN?p=preview

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:template name="dosomething">
        <xsl:text>A function that does something</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:call-template name="dosomething"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You need a testing environment that will display error messages.

Comment: could you please give more info .I am begineer in xslt ? which testing env ?

Comment: I would strongly recommend installing an XML IDE such as oXygen or Stylus Studio. A good environment for editing, running, and debugging XSLT will save you a lot of time and frustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xsl:call-template` cannot be at the top level of your stylesheet. It must only be used within a template body, for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:template name="dosomething">
        <xsl:text>A function that does something</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="dosomething"/>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: it is giving error https://plnkr.co/edit/TN1BN5Yao5Z63RDcBGlN?p=preview

Comment: You can see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/jz1PuPp Also, the code in your link is your original code, not the code suggested by me.

Comment: thanks ..!! could you please tell me why it is showing `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` in result

Comment: Because that is the default, unless you override it using[`xsl:output`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#output).